# PHP won't echo user input

Tags: php, html, forms, get

Kinda' new to this, so if my question is commonly asked or doesn't really make any sense I'm sorry. I'm trying to get PHP to echo the user's input to a form on the screen. Whenever I test out the form nothing changes. What would be your approach to this issue?

```
 <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<center><form name="name" method="get" class="form" id="nameInput">
  <center><h4>Name</h4></class></center>
  <center><input>
  
<center><div><form name="post" method="get" class="form" id="postInput">
  <center><h4>Post</h4>
  <center><input></div>
  <center><div><button id="postButton">Post</button></div>

<?php 
if(empty($_GET['name']) && empty($_GET['post'])){
  echo "<h3>test</h3>";
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  $post = $_GET['post'];
 

}else{
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  $post = $_GET['post'];
  echo "<h3> User: $name </h3>";
  echo "<h3> Post: $post </h3>";
}

?>
```

Comment: You may want to look at adding some `</form>` tags at some point 

Comment: You should take a step back and learn how to write HTML properly first, you're missing closing tags, input name, button type, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:-**

```
<body>
  <center>
    <form method="get" class="form" id="nameInput">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <input name="Name" type="name">
      <h4>Post</h4>
      <input name="Post type="textarea">
      <br><input type="submit" name="sub">
    </form>
  </center>

  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['sub'])) {
    if(empty($_GET['Name']) && empty($_GET['Post'])) {
      echo '<h2>Name: '.$_GET['Name'].'</h2>';
      echo '<h2>Post: '.$_GET['Post'].'</h2>';
    }
  }
  ?>
<script src="Index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The mistake was that you were give the name attribute to the form element.Each input should have its own name, Not the form.And try keeping the post and name inputs in one form.

***Hope this helps.***

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help you get started:

```
<form method="get" class="form">
    <center>
        <strong>Name</strong>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
    </center>
    <center>
        <strong>Post</strong>
        <input type="text" name="post" value="" />
    </center>
    <center>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
    </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the main problem is caused by your `HTML` code.

Mozilla says;

> The [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) HTML element represents a document section containing
> interactive controls for submitting information .

So, you need to all `input` / `textarea` etc. elements should be in a form. To do this and made it more simple, I wrote below code snippet. This will be more meaningful on this example;

```
<form method='GET'>
    <!-- INPUT Start -->
    <input type="text" name='name'>
    <input type="text" name='post'>
    <!-- INPUT End -->

    <!-- SEND BUTTON Start -->
    <input type="submit" value='send'>
    <!-- SEND BUTTON End -->
</form>
```

Another important attribute of the `<form>` HTML element is `action='where_are_you_going_path'` but now this is unnecessary because you want to redirect the same page that you form.

Secondly, you are getting some PHP error when you open your page;

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: name
>
> ..

This happens because you checked the `$_GET` array incorrectly. Because you cannot check whether it is empty or not to an index that has not yet been assigned.

To handle this problem, you can try [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.isset.php) method.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['post'])){
      echo "<h3> User:".$_GET['name']." </h3>";
      echo "<h3> Post: ".$_GET['post']." </h3>";
    }
?>
```

I would like to kindly suggest this; learn the HTML / CSS Basics using [Mozilla Documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started) after that jump to the `PHP`. This will be easier for you.